# using font awesome icon - how to add multiple random pre-filled emails to one single button? (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, email, hyperlink, font-awesome

I have a font awesome icon and I am trying to figure out how I can have multiple pre-filled emails that pop up each time I click the same button.
My code so far:
(In HTML)

```
<li><a href=""></script>"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
```

(In Javascript)

```
var diffEmails = [
        ''
        '' 
        ''
        ''

    ];

    function randomEmails() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('emails');
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * diffEmails.length);
        location.href = diffEmails[i];
        elem = i;
    }
    <a href=""> onClick="randomEmails();"></a>
```

Comment: @horrible I tried the code but it's not working. When I try to click on my font awesome icon nothing pops up

Answer (score 0):

```js
var diffEmails = [
  'bob@bob.com',
  'email@email.com',
  'cool@cool.com',
  'this@this.com',
];

function randomEmails() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('emails');
  var i = parseInt(Math.random() * diffEmails.length);
  var content = diffEmails[i];
  elem.textContent = content;
}
```

```html
<li><a onClick="randomEmails();"><i id="emails">this</i></a></li>
```